# Update ng-model in a textarea when the value change in a function

Tags: angularjs

I have this issue :

```
<textarea ng-model="modelToUpdate" rows="4" cols="50">
```

And when i do this in a called function in my script :

```
$scope.modelToUpdate = "test"
```

I'd like to see the changement directly in the textarea.

Comment: It will. as long as controllers are same and data-binding you are doing is correct.

Comment: so whats the issue? That should work

Comment: share your entire html and js or share a fiddle link.

Comment: you are right it works in this case but my issue is more complicated than this example. I don't know if i can share the code because i am using a framework and when i change the value it doesn't change in the textarea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you closing down the textarea tag ??

```html
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl" class="container">
  <textarea ng-model="modelToUpdate" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
</body>
```

See the plunker below for more information.

https://plnkr.co/edit/u6kcu9JUTGZ74f4VJDxT